# React using refs for child components

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-ref

I want to call a function from a child component inside of the parent component. I understood I could use React createRef as a solution. So far I tried it but the value of current remains null. Maybe I forgot something but I can't figure it out. If I could fix it via another way it will be also fine.

My example:

```
import * as React from 'react';
import FormComponent from "./FormComponent";
import CalendarComponent from "./CalendarComponent";
import LinearProgress from '@material-ui/core/LinearProgress';
import {connect} from "react-redux";
import DialogComponent from "../../../shared/modules/dialog/components/DialogComponent";

class WeeklyTimeTrackingComponent extends React.Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      dialogOpen: false
    }

    this.formComponentRef = React.createRef();

    this.openDialog = this.openDialog.bind(this);
    this.handleClose = this.handleClose.bind(this);
    this.handleSave = this.handleSave.bind(this);

  }

  openDialog = () => {
    this.setState({dialogOpen: true});
  }

  handleClose() {
    this.setState({
      dialogOpen: false
    });
  }

  handleSave() {
    console.log(this.formComponentRef.current, "COMPONENTS REFS");
  }

  render(){
    return (
      <div className="weekly-timetracking">
        {this.props.isFetching && (
          <LinearProgress />
        )}
        <CalendarComponent />
        <DialogComponent
          open={this.state.dialogOpen}
          onHandleClose={this.handleClose}
          onHandleSave={this.handleSave}
          title="Add new time registration"
          buttonText="Save">
          <FormComponent ref={this.formComponentRef} />
        </DialogComponent>
        <button
          className="btn btn-primary"
          onClick={this.openDialog}
        >Add project</button>
      </div>

    )
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = state => {
  return {
    isFetching: state.timeTracking.isFetching || false
  };
};

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(WeeklyTimeTrackingComponent);
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of passing ref you can pass desired method to child component and call it from there, example:

```
class Parent extends Component {
  example() {
    console.log("test");
  }

  render() {
    return <Child func={this.example.bind(this)} />
  }
}
class Child extends Component {
  render() {
    return <button onClick={this.props.func}>Click me</button>
  }
}
```

Same thing using function components

```
const Parent = () => {
  const example = () => console.log("test");

  return <Child func={example} />
}
const Child = ({func}) => {
  return <button onClick={func}>Click me</button>
}
```

Comment: I'm re-using the child component and the child component retains a function which I want to call from the parent

Comment: Data in react shouldn't flow in both directions, it's not built to work this way. If you want to do something in Parent component based on some event in children you should pass function to be called from Child component, not the other way around. If something in Child should change based on Parent you should just pass it as a prop from Parent. Can you elaborate on what you're trying to achieve?

Comment: I'm trying to re-use the form component. This time from inside of a dialog, so I want to save the form after the handleSave method is called from the DialogComponent. The method for saving the form is inside the FormComponent

Comment: So you can pass `handleSave` to `FormComponent` as a prop and call it from `FormComponent`. Eg. `<FormComponent onSubmit={this.handleSave} />`. FormComponent can pass all its data to that method so that you can use them in `handleSave` method

Comment: Maybe I don't understand your answer but handleSave is a callback function from the DialogComponent. So when that one is called I know when the save button is clicked inside the WeeklyTimeTrackingComponent. The actual save method is inside FormComponent where I want to keep it.

Comment: Oh, now I understand the problem correctly. Again, that's not how things should work in React but what you can try to do is publish/subscribe pattern. You can pass subscribe method to FormComponent and use it to subscribe to Submit event passing its saving method. Then in Dialog class you can invoke all methods that subscribed to this event. Give me 10 minutes and I'll be back with an example

Comment: Note that useEffects works similar as `componentDidUpdate` + `componentDidMount` and returned functions is like `componentWillUnmount`:

https://codesandbox.io/s/subscribe-example-cg2dk

Comment: Thanks for this solution. I'm going to look for implementing it. Btw, do you advise to place the save of the form in a higher component?

Comment: If you have different Form component(s) with the same saving logic - that wouldn't be a bad idea(render prop might be better tho). Although I'd suggest keeping one directional data flow - if you need to use something in parent component than either move it higher if you can or use mobx/redux to handle that from the very top. You can also use React.Context to extract saving logic and use it from wherever similar to mobx/redux.